# Terraform import resource within nested directories

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I've created a VPC peering connection in terraform with a new VPC created in Terraform and an existing one that was created in the AWS console.

I need to be able to import the existing VPC's route table so I'm able to add a new route referencing the vpc_peering_connection_id. However, i'm running into different errors trying to import and would happily take some guidance here.

This is the command I'm running in the cli while being in the root directory of the project-

```
terraform import aws_route_table.main rtb-12345
```

this is what I get back-

```
Error: resource address "aws_route_table.main" does not exist in the configuration.

Before importing this resource, please create its configuration in the root module. For example: 
resource "aws_route_table" "main" {
  # (resource arguments)
}
```

It's a pretty large project but this is the basic project structure-

```
-root directory
 -aws
  -main.tf
  -route_table
   -main.tf
 -main.tf
```

I do have the configuration the error is asking for in the route_table folder main.tf file as:

```
resource "aws_route_table" "main" {
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.default.id
}
```

I am also referencing the aws folder in the root directory > main.tf file

```
module "aws" {
  source = "./aws"
}
```

and then referencing the route_table folder in the aws directory > main.tf file

```
module "route_table" {
  source = "./route_table"
}
```

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here and how exactly to import the route table successfully. I would appreciate any help here, thanks!

Comment: Can you try with `terraform import module.aws.aws_route_table.main rtb-12345`?

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work either. getting the same error `Error: resource address "module.aws.aws_route_table.main" does not exist in the configuration.`

Comment: Then it means that your question does not correctly reflect your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to declare the "route_table" module in the main.tf of the root directory.

```
module "route_table" {
  source = "./aws/route_table"
```

After that import the resource using this command:

```
terraform import module.route_table.aws_route_table.main rtb-12345
```